# Find a random user according to a distribution based on the number of users' "likes"

Tags: swift, random

I'm trying to find the most efficient approach to randomly pick a user from my users table.

This would be very easy if the expected distribution was uniform : same probability for every user.

But in my case, I want this probability to be based on the number of 'likes' received by the user : the more 'likes' the user got, the most probable is to pick this user.
I know that GameKit provides a class `GKGaussianDistribution` to generate random numbers following a Gaussian Distribution, but I don't think this fulfill my needs.

Another approach would be to fill an array with a unique Id for every "likes" from every users, and to pick one of them with `arc4random_uniform()`, and then look-up to its owner user, but I'm not sure that it is the most efficient way to proceed.

I guess this is a common problem that many of us had to resolve once in a life ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use a roulette wheel algorithm. It's essentially the same as your idea of an array of unique ids but is better optimised for space (not time though).

Here's how it works:

- Arrange all the users in an array.
- Assign a range to each user as follows

  ```
  var totalLikes = 0
  for user in users
  {
      user.likeRange = totalLikes ..< (totalLikes + user.likes)
      totalLikes += user.likes
  }
  ```
- Use a random number generator to pick a value in the range `0 ..< totalLikes`
- Find the user in the array for which the random number falls within the user's `likeRange`

  ```
  let selectedUser = users.find { $0.likeRange.contains(randonNumber) }
  ```

  That's going to be a linear search but you can use a binary search to optimise based on the lower bound of each user's `likeRange`.

Comment: Yes indeed, it is better optimized like that. I'm still waiting a few more hours for more ideas or built-in swift solutions. If none, I will accept your answer. Thanks JeremyP !